# Reference for endomorphisms preserving a flag.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a dimension $n>0$ vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and let
$$
V=V_1 \supset V_2 \supset \dots \supset V_r \supset V_{r+1} = \{0\}
$$
be a (not necessarily complete) flag of subspaces.

Is there any description in the literature for the space $$ \{ \phi \in \mbox{End}(V) \mid \phi(V_i) \subset V_i, \, 1\leq i \leq r  \} $$ of endomorphisms of $V$ that preserve the flag?

I'm searching for references that deal with its Lie algebra structure and matrix description. I'm mostly interested in the particular case if we replace $\mbox{End}(V)$ by $\mathfrak{sl}(V)$.

References for particular cases are wellcome as well.

Comment: What sort of description do you want?  You can give a very simple explicit description in terms of matrices if you pick an appropriate basis for $V$.

Comment: To get you started, the endomorphism ring of a complete flag is isomorphic to the ring of upper triangular matrices.  I think adapting this description is what Eric is alluding to.

Comment: Yes, it seems it will be a "block-upper-triangular-ish" matrix.  I seek as much info as one can get for these Lie algebras.  I'll edit to specify the Lie algebra nature.

Comment: Do you know any "citeable" reference for this?

Comment: If you take the subgroup $P \subseteq \mathrm{GL}(V)$ which preserve a flag, this is called a *parabolic subgroup* of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$, and these are well-studied. The homogeneous space $\mathrm{GL}(V) / P$ is called the *flag variety*. There is a nice introduction to these in Fulton's *Young Tableaux*.